# Data Imputation for first two missing values alone

Tags: r

I have a yearly data record of 30 min interval data which contains date and its value ,such as

Table:1

```
 Time           Value
 01-01-13 0:00  5342179
 01-01-13 0:30  5342279
 01-01-13 1:00  5342379
 01-01-13 1:30  5342477
 01-01-13 2:00  5342576
 01-01-13 2:30  5342673
 01-01-13 3:00  5342772
```

The **Value** column in it is always an increasing one. But in-between, I'm also having missing data like,

```
 Table:2
 Time            Value
 05-05-13 11:00 6276870
 05-05-13 11:30 6277050
 05-05-13 12:00 **NA** 
 05-05-13 12:30 **NA**
 05-05-13 13:00 **NA**
 05-05-13 13:30 **NA**
 05-05-13 14:00 **NA**
 05-05-13 14:30 6277202 
 05-05-13 15:00 6277294
```

From the above table:2,  I need to impute data for the first two missing rows(05-05-13 12:00 & 05-05-13 12:30) alone and the rest missing values be as it is NA. The imputed value for the first two missing values need to be continuous (Increasing Order).

Like this set of records, there are further missing values in the same file out of which the first two missing values needs to imputed as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `table2[is.na(table2$value),] <- newvalue` you want to assign could do the trick.

Comment: the NA needs to be searched from the entire record and the above process needs to proceed,so table2[3,] <- value wouldn't work.